# SSRS Matrix percentages

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, percentage

Here's the report:[image: report table]

This is how I got the percentages for column the '%Change of most recent year".

```
=((Last(Fields!Quantity.Value,"Child")  -  First(Fields!Quantity.Value)) / First(Fields!Quantity.Value))`

= ((54675 - 55968)/55968 ) = -2.31%'
= ((54675 - 57849)/57849)  = -5.49%'
```

It will always take the first year '2012' in this case and get the percentages against each other year. If I enter the years 2005,2004,2003,2002,2001 it will always take the first year and do a percentages against each additional year. 2005 to 2004, 2005 to 2003, 2005 to 2002 and so on. I can have as many as 2 column (year) to many columns.

I need to do it for the Total and Subtotal but it won't work because it's in a different scope.

```
data is     = row Child group
Sub Total:  = row Parent group
Total:      = row Total group
Year        = Column Period group
```

Query use to get result.

```
 SELECT     MEMBERSHIP_CODE
, PERIOD, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Distinct_ID
, SUM(QUANTITY) AS Quantity
, '01-Personal' AS Child
, '01-Overall' AS Parent
, 'Total' as Total
  FROM         vf_Sshot AS vfs
INNER JOIN vProd AS vP ON vfs.PRODUCT_CODE = vP.PRODUCT_CODE
INNER JOIN vMem_Type vMT on vMT.Member_Type = vfs.Member_Type
  WHERE  (PERIOD IN ( (SELECT Val from dbo.fn_String_To_Table(@Periods,',',1))))                  
      AND (vMT.MEMBER_TYPE NOT IN ('a','b','c')) 
      AND (vfs.STATUS IN ( 'A', 'D', 'C')) 
      AND (MEMBERSHIP_CODE NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF' ))
      and vP.PROD_TYPE in ('DUE','MC','SC')
  and vMT.Member_Record = '1'
 GROUP BY MEMBERSHIP_CODE, PERIOD
```

Any ideas?

How would I produce this output?

TOTAL: 57,573 58,941 57,573 61,188 57,573 61,175 57,175

[image]

Comment: Can you make changes to the query that produces your dataset?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer not to. That query is just a part of a bunch of unions. The difference in the union is the Child, Parent, and Total. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone???????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Latest version of ssrs has a solution for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-previous-function?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way of solving your problem. In your query, identify the sum for the latest period on a separate column (you can transform your query into a CTE, so that you don't have to change your base query a lot):

```
WITH query AS (
   SELECT     MEMBERSHIP_CODE
     , PERIOD, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Distinct_ID
     , SUM(QUANTITY) AS Quantity
     , '01-Personal' AS Child
     , '01-Overall' AS Parent
     , 'Total' as Total
  ...
UNION
   SELECT
  ...
)
SELECT
   A.MEMBERSHIP_CODE,
   A.PERIOD,
   A.Distinct_ID,
   A.Child,
   A.Parent,
   A.Total,
   A.Quantity,
   B.Quantity AS LastPeriodQuantity
FROM
   query A INNER JOIN
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MEMBERSHIP_CODE, Distinct_ID, Child, Parent ORDER BY PERIOD DESC) as periodOrder FROM query) B ON
A.MEMBERSHIP_CODE = B.MEMBERSHIP_CODE AND
A.DISTINCT_ID = B.DISTINCT_ID AND
A.Parent = B.Parent AND
A.Child = B.Child AND
A.Total = B.Total AND
B.PeriodOrder = 1
```

And then on all your totals/subtotals/columns you will be accessing a column that is being grouped/filtered by the same rules than your denominator. Your expression can remain, for all cells, something like this: 
`=(Fields!LastPeriodQuantity.Value -  Fields!Quantity.Value) / Fields!Quantity.Value`

Comment: I really would prefer to do it in SSRS and not a query. Thanks!